# Subtotal and copy/paste with variable range

Tags: vba, variables, subtotal

I'm trying to figure out Excel VBA code to add subtotal (=SUBTOTAL(9,__:_) formulas to multiple Total Rows within a worksheet (red boxed).

The issue is that the range for the subtotals can be any height. Per the image below, the hope is that the VBA code would be able to identify when "Total" is present in column B and then proceed to add a subtotal formula in that row for columns E to J. The subtotal formula would need to pull the above balances up until there is a blank cell in order to calculate the amount for the particular client (the length of the range is signified by the arrows in the image below). The range could be any number of rows so has to be fully variable.

In addition, trying to add a subtotal at the very bottom of the worksheet (last row + 2) that should extend up to the very top of the row (blue arrow).

Finally, I need to find a way to copy the client name (green rectangles in column B) next to the total cells (copy to column C). The number of invoices can vary for each client so it would have to identify where the client name is located and then copy the name down to the bottom where the client total is being calculated.

Any help in this would be greatly appreciated!!

[image: Sample Aging]

```
Sub totalAllClients()
    Dim rng As Range, rngsb As Range, addr As String

    With Worksheets("Sheet1")
        With Intersect(.Columns(2), .UsedRange)
            Set rng = .Find(What:="total", After:=.Cells(1), MatchCase:=False, _
                            LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious)
            If Not rng Is Nothing Then
                addr = rng.Address(0, 0)
                Do
                    rng.Offset(0, 1).FormulaR1C1 = _
                        "=index(c2, match(""zzz"", r1c2:r[-1]c2))"
                    rng.Offset(0, 3).Resize(, 6).FormulaR1C1 = _
                        "=subtotal(109, r[-1]c:index(c, match(""zzz"", r1c2:r[-1]c2)))"
                    Set rng = .FindNext(After:=rng)
                Loop Until rng.Address(0, 0) = addr

                rng.Offset(2, 3).Resize(1, 6).FormulaR1C1 = _
                    "=aggregate(9, 3, r2c:r" & rng.Row & "c)"
            End If
        End With
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Welcome! Could you add in the code you've produced so far, so we can help you along?

Comment: Hello, I have added the code as it is currently stated.  I have this as a separate macro at the moment but would like to add this to another macro I have in place to take care of everything all at once.  If there is any way to perform this subtotal macro using ActiveSheet. that would be preferred.  Thanks a bunch for your help :)

Comment: Your code seems to be doing everything you wanted already, so well done! As for using ActiveSheet, this should be as simple as changing `With Worksheets("Sheet1")` to `With ActiveSheet`. Is there anything else you needed?

Comment: The code isn't working though for some reason.  Not sure what is wrong at this point.  And special thanks to the help that was provided in coming up with this code.

Comment: It seem to be working for me. Does the result not match what you were expecting? If so, what are the differences? Does the code throw up an error? If so, what error and where?

Comment: There is not error at all. But I run the macro and nothing seems to happen.  And I check the total lines and there are no formulas added.